# RouterLinkActive="selected" not applying the corresponding styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I was following along this tutorial to implement a toggled navbar in my angular app [Link](https://codepen.io/angeladelise/pen/VwaNeab)

I managed to turn the toggled logic in javascript to work in my angular app, but the action when a filed is selected does not seem to work for some reason I used `routerLinkActive="selected"` and replaced  `&-active` in the links css code with `selected` so the css properties get applied but without a result.

How do I fix this?

Here is the code I used :

MARKUP

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="list-items">
      <svg
        class="nav__expand"
        viewBox="0 0 256 512"
        width="100"
        title="angle-right"
        (click)="toggleSidebar()"
      >
        <path
          d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z"
          style="stroke: none; fill-rule: nonzero; fill: white; fill-opacity: 1"
        />
      </svg>

      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__listitem">
          <a routerLink="/sources" routerLinkActive="selected">
       
            <p>Reconciliation</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__listitem nav__listitem">
          <a routerLink="/sources" routerLinkActive="selected">
      
            <p>Data sources</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__listitem">
          <a routerLink="/files" routerLinkActive="selected">
       
            <p>Uploaded files</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__listitem">
          <a routerLink="/reports" routerLinkActive="selected">
        
            <p>Generated reports</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__listitem">
          <a href="#">
         
            <p>Logout</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
:root {
  /*   color variables */
  --clr-primary: #51bbe5;
  --clr-primary-hover: #29e6a7;
  --clr-primary-dark: #039d69;
  --clr-gray100: #f9fbff;
  --clr-gray150: #f4f6fb;
  --clr-gray200: #eef1f6;
  --clr-gray300: #e1e5ee;
  --clr-gray400: #767b91;
  --clr-gray500: #4f546c;

  /*   border radius */
  --radius: 0.2rem;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--clr-gray100);
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px var(--clr-gray300);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;

  &__expand {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    fill: var(--clr-gray400);
    background-color: #51bbe5;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px var(--clr-gray300);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotatez(-180deg);
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
      fill: white;
    }
  }

  &__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    &item {
      list-style: none;
      transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
      border-left: 6px solid transparent;
      cursor: pointer;

      &:first-child {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
      }

      &:hover {
        background-color: #f5f6fa;
      }

      a {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
        align-items: center;
        color: var(--clr-gray400);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      svg {
        fill: var(--clr-gray400);
        width: 2rem;
      }

      &selected {
        background-color: var(--clr-gray200);
        border-left: 6px solid var(--clr-primary);

        svg,
        p {
          color: var(--clr-primary);
          fill: var(--clr-primary);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //close state
  &-closed &__expand {
    transform: rotatez(0deg);
  }

  &-closed &__listitem p {
    display: none;
  }
}
.page-content-container {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #f5f6fa;
}
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

router module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'sources', component: DataSourcesComponent },
      { path: 'files', component: FilesComponent },
      { path: 'reporthistory', component: ReporthistoryComponent },
      { path: 'report', component: ReportComponent },
      { path: 'fdatasource', component: FdatasourceComponent },
      { path: 'sdatasource', component: SdatasourceComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'ModalComponent', component: ModalComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure and css structure don't match. Add the `selected` as class in your css file, and place it as a `a` tag child, it should be something like this:

```
a {
     display: flex;
     gap: 1rem;
     align-items: center;
     color: var(--clr-gray400);
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: 500;

     &.selected {
       background-color: var(--clr-gray200);
       border-left: 6px solid var(--clr-primary);
       ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Arsen Galloghlyan thank you for your response, you are absolutely right I had a problem with the HTML and CSS structure, now the class seems to target the selected item however it does fill completely like the example in the link it looks more like this [link](https://ibb.co/YpStMFy)  do you have any idea why?

Comment: any fix in mind for this problem, before I can mark your question as complete?

Comment: So, you mean the class still exists in a link despite you change the route?

Comment: Can you please share youre router module as well? Seems there are also some issues

Comment: Hey @Arsen Galloghiyan i edited my question with the router, please let me know if you need anything else and thank you for your help.

Comment: You have two ' routerLink="/sources" ' after each other, so in that case when you click one of them the active class applies in two anchor tags.

Comment: yes I was well aware of that, the problem as I asked, was when a route is selected it does not fill completely like the example link I added...